# HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath and Unit Test

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, hosting

In my WCF code I need to know the physical location of the service, thus I used `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath`.

But unit test project is unable to get value, normal to me, since the hosting environment is different.

What solution do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the manifest full path. Not exactly what you are asking for, but the directory path should be right.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(typeBeingTested)).Location
```

Comment: It does not work, my WCF is hosted in IIS thus I get `s = "c:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\root\\134d68ef\\ccb77aaa\\assembly\\dl3\\dba7079a\\0d7d9d95_6675cd01\\MyServices.DLL"`

Comment: Based on your question mentioning System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment I thought the problem was that the unit test did not run in IIS...

Answer (score 0):

I used `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and it works with a bit trick.

In WCF service I get D:\MyProjects\MyService\ and in unit test I get D:\MyProjects\MyService.Tests\bin\Debug\, so I have to create some post-build event in unit test project to take care the location discrepancy.